# JWT token is not working on some PC in Vuejs SPA

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, jwt, express-jwt

I am using JWT in vuejs application, surprisingly, the login is working in my PC and Mobile. It's not working on my second PC or any others.

It returns the token in the network tab. but the token is not saving in local storage.
[image]

And this is all on the live server. I used incognito mode. it's working in my PC.
I don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: Which browsers does it not work?

Comment: @sam with me it's working on all browsers, on other PC, it's not working on any of them

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: NO Errors! Clean